# Angular access controller scope from nested directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

this fiddle represents what i am trying to do: 
http://jsfiddle.net/d1001001/dwqw6/.
The grid directive needs to grab some data from controller, but since it's nested in the modal directive, which has isolated scope, it doesn't have access to controller's scope. If i
 put it like this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <grid data="data" cols="cols"></grid>
</div>
```

it works.

Is there a solution to this? I don't feel like passing the data and cols variables to the modal directive as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<div ng-transclude></div>
```

instead of

```
<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
```

in the template of `modal` directive.

Comment: And what if there was `ng-include` directive in the `modal` directive template and I wanted to access controller scope in the included template?

Comment: @d1001001 Use $parent